# Problem creating a build via docker and dotnet core console app

Tags: c#, linux, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I am trying to build my console app into a docker image but I keep on running into an error stating:
ERROR [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "./WebScrapper.csproj"                                                                                      0.6s

> [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "./WebScrapper.csproj":
> #12 0.525 A fatal error occurred, the folder [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not contain any version-numbered child folders

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "./WebScrapper.csproj"]: exit code: 131

My docker file looks as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-bullseye-slim-arm32v7 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim-arm32v7 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebScrapper.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebScrapper.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebScrapper.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebScrapper.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebScrapper.dll"]
```

I am not sure what seems to be the issue

My csproj file looks as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.46" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: change 'RUN dotnet restore "./WebScrapper.csproj"' to simply 'RUN dotnet restore'. When executed in the correct folder, the command will automagically use your .csproj by default

Comment: change `COPY ["WebScrapper.csproj", "."]` to `COPY WebScrapper.csproj` .`

Comment: 'WORKDIR "/src/."' is not required and should break the docker-build as well. 'dotnet build' is run in the same path as the previous 'dotnet restore' - no need to change path. For 'dotnet build' the same rules apply as for my last comment - no need to specify your .csproj specifically.